# Correct way to return exception information from main process to renderer process

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

In electronjs, what is the recommended way to return exception information from main process to renderer process? eg: instead of throwing an exception in the main process below, how should i change the code to handle the exceptions and pass this information to the renderer process? 
In my example below, the user will input a youtube url that might be invalid. I would like to handle the exception and provide the user a message to check the input youtube url.

**main.js:**

```
exports.getUrlInformation=(arg)=>
{
  var url = arg;
  var options = [];
  ytdl.getInfo(url, options, function(err, urlInformation) 
  {
    if (err) throw err;  
    mainWindow.webContents.send('UrlInformation', urlInformation);
  });
}
```

**index.js:**

```
var {ipcRenderer, remote} = require('electron');  
var mainProcess = remote.require("./main.js");

class YouTubeDownloaderForm extends React.Component 
{
  constructor(props) 
  {
    super(props);
    this.state = 
    {
      url: '', 
      urlsInformation:[]
    };
    this.handleAddClick = this.handleAddClick.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);      
    this.handleChangeClick = this.handleChangeClick.bind(this);
    this.handleUrlChange = this.handleUrlChange.bind(this);
    this.updateUrlInformation = this.updateUrlInformation.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() 
  {
    ipcRenderer.on('UrlInformation', this.updateUrlInformation)
  } 
  componentWillUnmount() 
  {
    ipcRenderer.removeListener('UrlInformation', this.updateUrlInformation)
  }
  updateUrlInformation(event, arg) 
  {
    var urlsInformation = this.state.urlsInformation;
    urlsInformation.push(arg);
    this.setState({urlsInformation: urlsInformation});
  }
  handleAddClick(event) 
  {      
    mainProcess.getUrlInformation(this.state.url);
  }
```

Comment: why are you doing this in the main process?

Comment: I am doing this in the main process, because I plan to expand the code to be able to download youtube videos\mp3's. I am assuming that these will be CPU intensive, and therefore are part of the main process instead of the renderer process.

Answer (score 1):

The main process is mostly for creating windows and accessing Electron API's which are restricted to the main process. Doing CPU intensive work in the main process will also cause glitches in the renderers too as the main process is used by the renderers to talk to the GPU processes.

Checkout [this article](https://codeburst.io/deep-dive-into-electrons-main-and-renderer-processes-7a9599d5c9e2) about the differences between the main and renderer processes and what you should be using each for.

Downloading can be achieved in the render using async code which will not block them. If you have real CPU intensive work this should be run in either Web Workers or in extra renderer processes. [electron-remote](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-remote) can make the process of bumping CPU intensive work into other renderers a little less painful.